# My code isn't giving the user's the correct feedback. Any ideas how to fix this?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a very simple code that invokes a stored procedure. The stored proc is used for sending out reminders to user's on expiring account.

When a user enters correct email address, the user gets a reminder email with the message, "Reminder sent successfully"

This is exactly what we want.

However, if the user enters an invalid email address, the user still sees same message, "Reminder sent successfully"

This is not good.

Can you please help with what I am doing wrong?

Please see entire (actual) code below:

```
Protected Sub BtnSubmit_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.ImageClickEventArgs) Handles BtnSubmit.Click

Dim oConnection As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("sConnectionString").ConnectionString)
Dim oCommand As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand()
Try
    oConnection.Open()
    oCommand.Connection = oConnection
    oCommand.CommandText = "AcountExpiration"
    oCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    oCommand.Parameters.Add(New SqlParameter("@Email", Data.SqlDbType.VarChar, 50)).Value = Email.Text
    Dim adpt As New SqlDataAdapter(oCommand)
    Dim ds As New DataSet()
    adpt.Fill(ds)
    oCommand.ExecuteReader()
    lblMsg.Text="Reminder successfully sent"
Catch ex As SqlException
    Response.Write("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>alert('" + ex.Message + "')</SCRIPT>")
Finally
    oConnection.Close()
End Try
End Sub
```

c# solution is welcome as well.

```
        Dim scmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("AcountExpiration", Conn)
        scmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
        scmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", Email.Text)
        'Dim r As SqlDataReader = scmd.ExecuteReader()
        Dim validEmail As Boolean = False
        Dim reader As SqlDataReader = scmd.ExecuteReader()

        While reader.Read()
            'if we are here then something got returned.
            'so probably a valid email.
            validEmail = True
        End While

        If validEmail = True Then
            lblMsg.Text = "Success"
        Else
            lblMsg.Text = "email does not exit on our system"
        End If
```

Comment: What in your code makes you think that the error message should be displayed? You don't have anything in the code you've posted that validates the email address.

Comment: @Kenny what does your stored procedure look like? and you could probably get away with an `if reader.Read()` as you only care that something got returned. I would suggest that your stored procedure is still returning rows regardless whether it finds a matching email address...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would not use a SqlDataAdapter or Dataset for this. just use the [SqlDataReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9kcbe65k.aspx)

```
bool validEmail = false;
SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader(); 

while (reader.Read())
{
   //if we are here then something got returned.
   //so probably a valid email.
   validEmail = true;
}
```

Or use [ExecuteScalar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
bool validEmail = Convert.ToBoolean(command.ExecuteScalar());
```

then

```
if(validEmail)
{

}
else
{

}
```

UPDATE

Will add an update for this as some people don't realise that certain code wont magically work. I have already included links for ExecuteScalar and ExecuteReader to show how to use these methods.

If you wanted to use ExecuteScalar you would have to change your stored procedure to return a value that could then be parsed as a Boolean.

The above methods is simply for checking if an email exists in the DB. No this does not valdate an email address, as I would expect that to occur before this code would be reached.

Comment: What is the boolean that you're assuming is returned from the sproc? Where is the email validation that will return the correct value?

Comment: @DanPuzey what are you talking about? obviously the OP has a user enter an email, if it exists in the db then send a email if not show an error message.

the ExecuteScalar is a good usage example of how when checking a db for if a value exists.

Comment: @DanPuzey who said anything about email validation?

Comment: Quoting the question directly: "if the user enters an invalid email address, the user still sees same message." The word "invalid" implies "validation" and there is nothing *explicit* in the question that explains what this means: does it mean invalid *formatting*, or an email that does not exist in the database already? Your answer assumes implementation details that are not known to exist.

Comment: @DanPuzey "Where is the email validation that will return the correct value?" what are you assuming here?

Comment: @DanPuzey why else would there be a DB connection to fire a storedproc if this is for a simple email validation?. Yes I agree the terminology of what "valid" means can be vague, but from the code example its pretty clear what the OP meant.

Comment: @DanPuzey, Thanks all for the feedbacks. When I said, "if user enters invalid email address", I meant that if the user enters an email address that doesn't exist on the database, I expected an exception to be raised that email doesn't exist, or not found.

The validation as far as formatting is concerned, is done on the markup.

Sorry about any confusion.

Comment: @Kenny you could use something similar to my example above for that purpose. You don't necessarily need SqlServer to throw an exception. But if that's the behaviour you desired, in your stored procedure you would have to check if any rows were returned from your query and then throw an exception if not.

Comment: @SecretSquirrel, I like your code but I still get same error message whether email address is exists on our system or not.

Please see my updated code. I am definitely missing something.

Is there a way to validate '@Email' against the email from db? I *think* that may be the issue.

Answer (score 2):

You have a couple of different options as I see it.

1. Have the sproc throw an error if the email address isn't valid.
2. Have validation on the dataset to check and make sure you are getting back the expected values. Only display the success message if there was actually a success.